# Google Maps API V3 Geocoding API not returning state

Tags: web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I need to find out whether a particular (well formatted) address is in "England", "Wales", "Scotland" or "Northern Ireland" if the address is in the UK.

My current requests to the Google Geocoding API return the city (e.g. "London") and the country ("United Kingdom") - both of these are useless to me.

Is there any way I can retrieve the information I need, or is a different web service required?

Comment: It appears the element I particularly need to access is administrative_area_level_1. Strangely enough, if I send the latitudes/longitudes back as a reverse geocode request, I can retrieve this information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the geocoding response does not return the administrative_area_level_1 for the UK when passing a complete address as a parameter.

However, in your case, what I would do is send the town name (instead of the complete address) to the geocoder which will return the data you need. Here some examples:

- [Manchester](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Manchester&sensor=false&region=uk)
- [Cardiff](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Cardiff&sensor=false&region=uk)
- [Glasgow](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Glasgow&sensor=false&region=uk)

Note that I have added the [Region Biasing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#RegionCodes) parameter to the query so you will need to change it if you want to use it outside the UK.

Comment: This is the closest I can get. However, the results are still inconsistent at best. For example, the query for [London](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=London&sensor=false&region=uk) still excludes the `administrative_area_level_1` information

Answer (score 1):

If your full address has the postal code you can determine this from the postal code prefix, which is tied to postal districts.

Northern Ireland:  BT
Wales: LL, NP, CF, SA, CH, SY
Scotland: AB, DD, FK, PA, DG, ZE, KA, G, EH, IV, KW

All others would be England, excluding post codes for oversea territories.

You can get general information on UK postal codes from:

http://www.townscountiespostcodes.co.uk/

Oversea territories postal codes can be found at Wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have these problems a while ago, but they started to appear for some Danish zip codes.
Unfortunately what I ended up doing was to query google twice.
The first time I send the zip code and extract the "formatted_address" from the response, urlencode it and use it in another request to the geocode API. This returns the "administrative_area_level_1" in most cases, but it does not for some of the zip codes in Copenhagen.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, for those arriving here via a Google search (like me), I had a similar problem. The Postcode list above by [Andrew - OpenGeoCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622104/andrew-opengeocode) was very helpful, although missing some postcode letters. I scoured the Google API results and I believe I have a comprehensive list now.

One thing to note: Southern/Republic of Ireland **doesn't** seem to return postcodes in the Maps API. My workaround was to use the Country Code (API country `short_name`).

Hopefully my little snippet will help some. You could easily adapt it into a function on its own (I use this within another function).

```
    if($('#postcode').val().match(/^(BT)/)){
        $('#country').val("Northern Ireland");
    } else if($('#postcode').val().match(/^(LL)|^(NP)|^(CF)|^(SA)|^(CH)|^(SY)|^(HR)|^(LD)/)){
        $('#country').val("Wales");
    } else if($('#postcode').val().match(/^(AB)|^(DD)|^(FK)|^(PA)|^(DG)|^(ZE)|^(KA)|^(G)|^(EH)|^(IV)|^(KW)|^(PH)|^(KA)|^(TD)|^(ML)|^(HS)/)){
        $('#country').val("Scotland");
    } else if($('#countryCode').val() == "IE"){
        $('#country').val("Republic of Ireland");
    } else if($('#countryCode').val() == "GB"){
        $('#country').val("England");
    }else{  
        $('#country').val(addressComponents.country); //if not UK postcode, return whatever Google gets for Country Name
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a webservice to do just that

https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/uk-boundaries-io

..simply it allows obtaining GeoJson for googleMaps..query by single or combining UK Postal Code(ex. ZE1 0AE) ,Sector, District, City, and Wards Boundaries

for example a UK District "Manchester"
.../boundary/uk?district=Manchester  will get you the below GeoJson(all sector boundaries in this district...

[image]